# how to have two different settings in sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I am doing web development and most of my work is in the following:

```
php
ruby
Rails (the framework)
CakePHP (the framework)
javascript
AngularJS (the framework)
jQuery (the js library)
html
css
```

I realized I have basically the following 3 scenarios in my development work:

1) for CakePHP

- use tabs for indentation
- indentation width is 4 spaces

2) for php development

- use spaces for indentation
- indentation width is 4 spaces

3) for everything else

- use spaces for indentation
- indentation width is 2 spaces

I think what I want to do is set my user defaults to the 3rd one and have individual project settings.

I know how to set User settings in sublime 3.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

in your User settings, use

```
  "tab_size": 2,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

in your CakePHP project settings, use

```
  "tab_size": 4,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
```

in your everyday php project settings, use

```
  "tab_size": 4,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

Project settings require you to save a project and the file generated is a JSON file usually named as `project-name.sublime-project`

Comment: You can also create a file called `PHP.sublime-settings` in your Sublime User package folder and put general PHP settings there.

Comment: @bungeshea How do I change from default settings to this general PHP settings?

Comment: Sublime Text will automatically use the PHP settings when you open up a file with a PHP file extension, or mark a file as PHP through `Set Syntax: PHP` from the Command Palette